# Routing in 10.8 Server - WiFI clients over VPN - Ethernet Clients not over VPN

Tags: vpn, osx-mountain-lion, openvpn

I'm not sure I have the right hardware for this, but....

I have a Mac Mini i7 Server with a built-in ethernet (en0) and a thunderbolt ethernet (en1) and the built in airport.

I would like to be able to configure a VPN (PPTP or OpenVPN using a client) connection to another location and then allow another device on the same 192.168.x.x network connect to the VPN via the Mac Mini Server on either en1 or over wireless.

However, I also want the Mac Mini Server to be able to send traffic over en0 bypassing the VPN.

Is this at all possible?

A scenario would be an Apple TV connecting over wifi or en1 to the Mac Mini Server and then being routed via the VPN. Meanwhile the Mac Mini is acting as a Plex Media Server and sending transcoded movies over en0, not via the VPN.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible.  I don't have a Mac, however I'm sure that it is conceptually similar to doing it under Linux.  After setting up your VPN (OpenVPN is a better choice then PPTP, but either should work fine), you need to do 3 things.  [ I note it does not really matter if you do it over the ethernet or WIFI interface ]

Let me define the machines for ease of reference:
REMOTE = OpenVPN Server outside your network
SERVER = Mac Mini
CLIENT = "Other device on same 192.168.x.x network"

1. Enable forwarding on SERVER.
2. Either enable routing to CLIENT across he VPN on the REMOTE (ie a 
   static route for CLIENT/SERVER Subnet)  or get the server to 
   masquerade/nat packets coming from CLIENT destined for remote.
3. Set a static route for REMOTE on CLIENT to go via SERVER.

I have no way of trying these things, but practically, I believe the following will work:

1. Enable packet forwarding by entering

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
   ```

   in a Terminal.
2. (This will depend on your setup).  For OpenVPN you can probably
   affect this change simply by adding a line to the OpenVPN config on
   REMOTE

   ```
   route IP.RANGE.OF.CLIENT NETMASK.OF.RANGE
   ```

   Alternatively try something like

   ```
   /sbin/ipfw add divert natd all from any to any via XXX
   ```

   On server to enable masquerading  (where XXX is either the wireless or
   ethernet interface)

   Alternatively have a look at http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021030055008917 for a starting point for 
   setting up a PPTP tunnel with Masquerading.
3. Use the command

   ```
   route -n add REMOTE.IP gw SERVER.IP
   ```

   on the CLIENT.
   (Have  a look at http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/ on how to make this permanant)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response, I'll try to follow it and then report back if that's okay?

Comment: Thanks again, had to look a few things up but this worked.